# Query mongodb for conditional conditions

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

How do i query mongo for the list of all non-private blogs along with the private blogs of currently logged-in user.

**Blog**(collection):
`_user_id: ref(User),
title: String,
body: String,
private: Boolean, default:false`

I can get all the non-private blogs with this query:

`Blog.find({_user_id: req.user}).where('private', false).exec();`

But I also want to get all the blogs which are marked private only by this current logged-in user.

Is this thing even possible using single query. Do I have to rely on advance mongodb features like map-reduce / aggregate .

Comment: Have you looked at using [`$or`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/or/#op._S_or)?

Comment: Yes, but I don't think that would help here cos I want both conditions.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`$or`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/or/#op._S_or) to include both cases in a single query:

```
Blog.find({$or: [
    // Non-private blogs
    {private: false},
    // Blogs of the current user
    {_user_id: req.user}
]}).exec(function(err, docs) { ... });
```

This will provide a union of the results of the two `$or` clauses.